# How to deserialize an image from API in .net c#

Tags: c#, json, image, rest

I would like to deserialize an image to .net through an API call. In the project's API the URI extended with the current person's Id (as a string query), then with that full URI a person's image shows up in Postman. So, I would need this URI's data in order to display each person's image on a search UI.

While debugging it seems something goes wrong with the API call. There is no data in there, the variable img is null. I am passing this method which is catching the exception, as there is no data.

What is wrong with this call? (img is null, byte array is null, etc.)

This is my APIHelper class' method.

```
public byte[] GetFaceImageByte(string faceId)     
{          
   var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
   var img =  restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<byte[]>(new RestRequest( $"/facevis/faces/{faceId}/image"), cancellationTokenSource.Token);                        
   return img.Result.RawBytes;
}
```

This is the other class' method where I would display the image.

```
private static BitmapImage LoadBitmapImageResource(Guid resourceName)     
{         
   try         
   {             
      APIHelper apiHelper = new APIHelper();                          
      var imgData = apiHelper.GetFaceImageByte(resourceName.ToString());                
      using var mStream = new MemoryStream(imgData);                 
         var img = new BitmapImage();                 
         img.BeginInit();                 
         img.StreamSource = mStream;                 
         img.EndInit();                 
         return img;         
   }         
   catch         
   {             
         return null;         
   }
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `using` for the Stream you then assign to the image. Once the method ends it will make the image invalid. Might not be an issue when using MemoryStream but in general. Also, you shouldn't really mix sync/async like you are (calling Result property), you need an await. What's in `(await img).RawBytes`, surely there's something?

Comment: I tried to make it async Task<> and await it, plus await it in the LoadBitmapImageResource method as well after I'm calling the GetFaceImageByte method, before the using. 
The result while debugging is imgData = (Task<byte>) Status = Faulted, Result = {Not yet computed}